# How do I get started with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need good resources for learning React - tutorials, video series, books, etc.

Some websites just provide the basics of React but I need guidance on how to get started with developing a full-fledged website with multiple react components.

Comment: Good to know: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

https://medium.mybridge.co/learn-react-js-from-top-45-tutorials-for-the-past-year-v-2018-28b7f4d4b2c4

React

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/all-the-fundamental-react-js-concepts-jammed-into-this-single-medium-article-c83f9b53eac2

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBuKtLgPR_zWYnrwv-JllpA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A71aqufiNtQ&t=1578s

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b

Redux

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBbSLZjvleMwldX8jGgXV6a

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL55RiY5tL51rrC3sh8qLiYHqUV3twEYU_

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGADILc3iUJzygCqC8Tt3bRXt

React Routing

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/beginner-s-guide-to-react-router-53094349669